# Systemd service - custom operation

Tags: systemd, services

I have a LSB script launching a daemon with commands like `start`, `stop`, `restart`, but also with custom commands, like `start-dump`.

Is it possible to achieve the same result with only a Systemd service unit definition? (no external script in /etc/init.d or whatever)

Note that `start-dump` would basically do a `/my/executable --dump`

Comment: On RH/CentOS/Fedora systems, my advice is to keep using `service`, which will allow extra verbs in `/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions` and fall through to systemd for start, stop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been 3 years since this question was asked but I had the same question and I think I have an answer.  You could create a systemd service and call it "foo-start-dump.service" and in that file have `ExecStart=/my/executable --dump`.  Then you could execute:

```
# systemctl start foo-start-dump.service
```